# How to retrieve user input for 3D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want user to be able to choose how many times he wants to write into 3D array and i know this can be done using scanf. Then I want user to give coordinates X, Y, Z (of an array) where he assigns some value. But what I want is to make user enter all X coordinates first of all, then Y and then Z.

So if user wants to write to array 3 times he gives, 3, 5, 7 (all-Xs coordinates), then on a new line 5, 6, 7 (all-Ys coordinates) and 3, 5, 1 (all-Zs coordinates) on a new line.

Whats the best method to obtain such user input and how would I implement it?

Comment: what makes it special? looks like a simpe doube-loop. also, where's your code?

Comment: The best method would be to go back to the drawing board, IMHO. You're writing the code. How and where you store the data is up to you. Things like that _really_ shouldn't depend on user input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to chew on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x[3], y[3], z[3], i;

    // Read all x's.
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    }

    // Read all y's.
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &y[i]);
    }

    // Read all z's.
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &z[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but a mock-up; you can make a simple change to allow the user to enter coordinates any number of times.

Comment: _"best method"_ are the keywords!

Answer (score 0):

Use three calls to `fgets()`. One for each axis.

Then parse the values out of the strings read, for example using `strtok()`.